# Match and replace full javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I match whole JavaScript function on current page? My JavaScript function is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    if( !success )
    {
        success = true;
        alert('Think first! Click CANCEL on the next page to receive a new gift.\n\n');
        window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/';
        return '\nClick CANCEL\n\nOver thousands of gifts have been given out, get yours today!\n\n';
    }
}
```

and I want dynamically match and replace this function to:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function()
{
    return ExitPopup();
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why not just assign (override) it, as you do in the second snippet?

Comment: *Please* don't use such annoying alerts when you try to close the page...

Comment: Why not edit the pages instead of doing it all dynamically?

Comment: the first function is already on the page which I get with curl and I want to change this function with my function

Answer (score 1):

can't you do

```
var newFunction = function()
{
    return ExitPopup();
}
```

and then

```
window.onbeforeunload = newFunction;
```